# Multiple insert from dynamic textbox sqlserver

Tags: php, sql-server

Please help whats wrong in my code! need to insert multiple data from dynamic textbox. Thanks in advance hope you can help me!

```
<?php       
if (isset($_POST['stnp1ecimSubmit'])) {

$test = $_POST['test'];
$test2 = $_POST['test2'];
$test3 = $_POST['test3'];
$test4 = $_POST["test4"];
$test5 = $_POST["test5"];


foreach($_POST['test'] as $a => $b){
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tbltest] WHERE 
tbltest='$test[$a]' ") ;
if($stmt){
$row = sqlsrv_has_rows( $stmt );
if ($row === true){

$user_error =" user is already exist!";
}else{


$query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbltest] (tbltest, tbltest2, tbltest3, 
tbltest4,tbltest5)
VALUES ('" . $test[$a] . "', '" . $test2[$a] . "', '" . $test3[$a] . "', '" . 
$test4[$a] . "', '" . $test5[$a] . "')";


$results = sqlsrv_query($conn , $query);
echo"  <script>alert('Successfully Added!')</script>";
exit();
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Here is my sample textbox

```
<input type="number" name="test1[]"   title="Enter Badge Number" style="width:150px;" placeholder="Enter Badge ID.." class="form-control" required autofocus>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your problem more thoroughly? Are you getting an error message? Is your data there? Any/all of this information will help us get you a better answer.

Comment: I dont get any error. if i clicked the button only 1 row can save not all inputed from dynamic textbox.